# Synchronization in a multi-threaded program versus between parent and child processes

Tags: multithreading, process, synchronization

As described in the title. What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 0):

While your question is not very specific, this is what I believe would best answer it:

In a multi-threaded program, there is a single process that has multiple threads. All these threads have their own stack, but share everything else. In other words, if you have (for example) a global variable, changing it in one thread will change it for all other threads. This is a form of communicating between different threads of the same process.

When you have a parent process and a child process, you have two different processes altogether that don't share anything (well, the child depends on the parent to stay alive, but that's an entirely different conversation). As you can't directly modify variables of the other process (like you could do with the global variable from earlier), to send data from one process to another you will need to use other techniques, the most common of which are pipes. You can think of pipes the same way you think of files: when you want to send data to another process, you write data to the pipe; when you want to get received data from another process, you read data from the pipe.

Here's a link with examples of how pipes work: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-demonstrate-fork-and-pipe/
Here's a link with examples of how accessing the same global variables in different threads works: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-c-2/

Glad to try clarify this if you have additional questions / if this doesn't answer your question

Edit: To tackle the "synchronisation" part: In a multi-threaded program, you can use structures like mutexes or barriers that are shared as a global variable and easily accessible by all the threads in your process.
In a multi-process program, you will need to synchronise using very similar techniques that are built as an abstraction layer over the inter-process communication system that I talked about above.
An example of such an abstraction layer is how MPI does synchronisation: https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-broadcast-and-collective-communication/
Of course, you can implement your own functions over the pipes.